# how to add a NavigationController to a UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I need to add a UINavigationController to a UIViewController,and don't use appDelegate.In my Controller I write like this

```
OneViewController *oneVC = [[OneViewControlelr alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:oneVC];

[self presendModalViewController:nav];
```

and it nothing to found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
[self presentModalViewController: nav animated:YES];
```

For more info, please visit [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  OneViewController *oneVC = [[OneViewControlelr alloc] initWithNibName:@"OneViewControlelr" bundle:nil];
  UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:oneVC];
  [self presentModalViewController: nav animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you dnt want navigationcontroller just try this

```
OneViewController *oneVC = [[OneViewControlelr alloc] initWithNibName:@"xibname" bundle:nil];
[self presendModalViewController:oneVC animated:YES];
[oneVC release];
```

if u want navigationController try this code

```
OneViewController *oneVC = [[OneViewControlelr alloc] initWithNibName:@"xibname" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:oneVC];
[self presendModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
[oneVC release];
[navigationController release];
```

Comment: `presendModalViewController`,it's should be 'presentModalViewcontroller'

Answer (score 0):

Just do like this in AppDelegate.m file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

SoapWebServiceViewController *root = [[SoapWebServiceViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:root];

    // Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
    [self.window addSubview:nav.view];    
}
```

Hope this help U

Answer (score 0):

```
OneViewController *oneVC = [[OneViewControlelr alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:oneVC];


AppDelegate *appDelegate=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
[[[appDelegate <viewController>]view] removeFromSuperview];  // put UIViewController reference into <viewController>
[[appDelegate window]addSubview:[[appDelegate nav]view]];
```